# Shopify - Adding Footer Nav

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm using Shopify's Debut theme and would like to add the footer navigation to the bottom. In the backend, I have two navigations, "Main menu" and "Footer menu" set up.

This works:

```
<ul>
{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
  <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

but this doesn't when I put "footer-menu":

```
<ul>
{% for link in linklists.footer-menu.links %}
  <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default footer menu is just `footer` not `footer-menu`.

So you should call `linklists.footer.links` instead.